# Sorting datatables in a dataset with the datatable.name

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, dataset

I'm reading some xml-files into a dataset, sort the datatable and generate for each row (if not exist) a new datatable in another dataset.

```
 foreach (FileInfo f in files)
            {
                if (f.Name.StartsWith("ID_" + lbl_ID.Text))
                {
                    dsDatei.Reset();
                    dsDatei.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + f.Name);

                    DataTable dtSort = dsDatei.Tables[0].Clone();
                    dtSort.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(Int32);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dsDatei.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        dtSort.ImportRow(dr);
                    }
                    dtSort.DefaultView.Sort = "Number";
                    dsDatei.Tables.RemoveAt(0);
                    dsDatei.Tables.Add(dtSort.DefaultView.ToTable());

                    ...some code

            foreach (DataRow dr in dsDatei.Tables[0].Rows)
               {

                   if (!dsAusdruck.Tables.Contains(dr[1].ToString()))
                            {
                                dsAusdruck.Tables.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                                dsAusdruck.Tables[dr[1].ToString()].Columns.Add("Position");
                                ...add more columns
                            }
                    ...some code
                }
            }
            }
```

My problem is that for example in the first xml file the number 144 is missing, in the second xml file the number 144 exist and the datatable with the name 144 is created at the end of the dataset.

Later I create a pdf-file with the dataset, for each datatable a new page. So I get the number 144 at the last page instead between the pages with the numbers 143 and 145.

So how is it possible to sort the datatables in the dataset?

Thanks

**Result for answer PinBack**

[image]

Comment: before you create the pdf, you could create a list with the available tables and sort it. Then create the pdf by using the sorted list

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that. Have you tried linq? `dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Sort()` Or you could loop through the Tables and remove the Table at the wrong index. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order the tables with Linq:

UPDATE (reorder the Tablecollection):

```
DataSet loDs = new DataSet();

loDs.Tables.Add(new DataTable("141"));
loDs.Tables.Add(new DataTable("142"));
loDs.Tables.Add(new DataTable("143"));
loDs.Tables.Add(new DataTable("145"));
loDs.Tables.Add(new DataTable("144"));

var loSortedDataTableList = loDs.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().OrderBy(item => int.Parse(item.TableName)).ToList();
loDs.Tables.Clear();

foreach (DataTable loDt in loSortedDataTableList)
{
    loDs.Tables.Add(loDt);
    Console.WriteLine(loDt.TableName);
}
```

Output is:

> 141
>   142
>   143
>   144
>   145

Comment: It's unlikely this will give the required result. OP doesn't name his tables, and even then sorting numeric strings will give a result like `1, 10, 100, 101, 11, 110, 111`. If he named the tables like `0001`, `0002`, `0003` ... `0101` etc then it might work.

Comment: OK, that could be. Then you just have to use this one: `.OrderBy(item => int.Parse(item.TableName))` or something else.

Comment: Put that in your answer and maybe show OP how to add a table name ;-)

Comment: Update answer. But I think all the tables have a name.

Comment: Then OP have to explain the criteria according to which he wants to sort the tables.

Comment: Sry for the delay and thanks for the answer but the sorting doesn't work. See my updated question with the screenshot. The tablename with the numbers 144 and 246 are not sorted

Comment: The code does not sort the collection inside the `DataSet`. It is only to get the Tables.
You might be able to clear the `DataSet` Tablecollection and add the Tables in the right order. See Update